# Add interceptor to spring boot mongodb rest example

Tags: spring, mongodb, interceptor, spring-boot

I am trying to add an interceptor to a simple Spring-boot-mongodb-rest app, as can be seen here : http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/, in order to perform certain actions after the default rest handler is invoked. Here is my MongoRepository, whose CRUD operation is called upon a POST request to the server:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "reminder", path = "reminder")
public interface ReminderRepository extends MongoRepository<Reminder, String> {

    List<Reminder> findBySendee(@Param("sendee") String sendee);

}
```

I am trying to register an interceptor for all HTTP requests by extending the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RemindxWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
         registry.addInterceptor(new RemindxInterceptor());
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the spring boot docs, I have not added the @EnableWebMvc annotation to this. While running the application, the addInterceptors function does get called and adds the interceptor. However, the given interceptor is not called after the POST handler is invoked. I am unable to figure out a way to have spring use this RemindxWebConfig for all MongoRepository http requests. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: I think Spring Data REST must have it's own `HandlerMapping`. If you can get a reference to it, you can probably add your interceptor there.

Comment: @DaveSyer I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251846/custom-default-headers-for-rest-api-only-using-spring-data-rest) which seems related to what I am trying to accomplish. However, now the overridden `repositoryExporterHandlerMapping` doesn't even get called..

Comment: Resolved. Forgot the @import the derived RestConfig class. Thanks!