# How to add Custom Interceptor in Spring data rest (spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.0)

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am working on the spring data rest services & facing some issue in the custom interceptors. Earlier I used spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.2.0 & added interceptor in following way.

```
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping repositoryExporterHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super
                .repositoryExporterHandlerMapping();

        mapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] { new MyInterceptor() });

        return mapping;
}
```

It worked perfectly fine for me. But when i upgraded to spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.0 version, I noticed that handlerMapping is hidden behind DelegatingHandlerMapping. Hence I tried to add interceptor in following way.

In one of my config class I have extended RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration class & override its method.

```
public class AppConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
@Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public DelegatingHandlerMapping restHandlerMapping()
    {
        RepositoryRestHandlerMapping repositoryMapping = new RepositoryRestHandlerMapping(super.resourceMappings(), super.config());
        repositoryMapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] { new MyInterceptor()});
        repositoryMapping.setJpaHelper(super.jpaHelper());
        repositoryMapping.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        repositoryMapping.afterPropertiesSet();

        BasePathAwareHandlerMapping basePathMapping = new BasePathAwareHandlerMapping(super.config());
        basePathMapping.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        basePathMapping.afterPropertiesSet();
        List<HandlerMapping> mappings = new ArrayList<HandlerMapping>();
        mappings.add(basePathMapping);
        mappings.add(repositoryMapping);

        return new DelegatingHandlerMapping(mappings);

    }
}
```

But after adding this some of my repository operations (findAll() operation on repository) start failing. If I removed this interceptors those operations worked fine. (In this interceptor I am just authenticate the user.)
Hence I am unable to understand problem here. Am I adding the interceptor in wrong way? Is there any other way to add the interceptor?

Comment: Why do you have to use Spring DATA Rest mappings to inject your interceptor? Wouldn't a regular Spring MVC interceptor or even Spring Security config suffice for authentication?

Comment: I tried to use normal spring MVC interceptor by adding following code. But this interceptor did get called for spring data rest operations.

Comment: public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }

}   AFAIK, you need to add the interceptor in RepositoryRestHandlerMapping & BasePathAwareHandlerMapping then only it will be called for spring data rest operation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not use `repositoryMapping.setInterceptors()` - it destoys the internal interceptors Spring placed there, and that's probably the reason some methods stopped working.

I suggest you override `jpaHelper()` method and put your interceptors into the `JpaHelper` object in `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`. Spring will should them to the global interceptor list.

But, again, if all you need is authentication, why not use a Spring Security filter?

EDIT: the solution above works only for `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping`, not for `BasePathAwareHandlerMapping`.

I suggest you declare a custom `MappedInterceptor` bean somewhere:

```
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor myMappedInterceptor() {
    return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/**"}, new MyInterceptor());
}
```

From my understanding of the source code Spring should automatically add this interceptor to all request handlers.

Comment: I have custom build service which does the authentication & authorization for all applications in my company. I have to use that service for my SDR services as well. I am calling that service through this interceptor.

Comment: Very well, then. Try the solution with JpaHelper. It seems like the proper way to do it.

Comment: Thanks IIya, that worked for me.                                                         @Override
 public JpaHelper jpaHelper() {
  if (IS_JPA_AVAILABLE) {
   
   JpaHelper helper = new JpaHelper();
   helper.getInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
   return helper;
    } else {
   return null;
  }
    
 }

Comment: IIYa, though this interceptor is working for RepositoryRestController, it is not working for @BasePathAwareController. I mean, request for the basepathawareController by pass the interceptor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These are two separate handlers. I browsed the sources and apparently you can just create a `MappedInterceptor` bean in your context and it will auto-register in all handlers. Try that!

Comment: Can you elaborate more what do you mean here?

Comment: Thanks for your response IIya. In this way I am able to add the interceptor for all controllers & its working fine.

Comment: I simply declared the `myMappedInterceptor()` inside my `@SpringBootApplication`. First solution after several that worked for me, thanks!