# Spring Data Rest Interceptor not working for CustomController

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a spring data REST application in which I have added a interceptor for authentication & authorization.

```
private static final boolean IS_JPA_AVAILABLE = ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.persistence.EntityManager",
            RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class.getClassLoader());



@Override
    public JpaHelper jpaHelper() {
        if (IS_JPA_AVAILABLE) {

            JpaHelper helper = new JpaHelper();
            helper.getInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
            return helper;
                } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In this application, I have few controllers as well. Some of them are @RepositoryRestController & other are @BasePathAwareController. I want to call the interceptor when a request comes to these controllers. For @RepositoryRestController the interceptor get called, but for @BasePathAwareController it is bypassed. 
How can I make this interceptor get called for both controller classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by adding mapped interceptor (thanks llya for your inputs). In the configuration class, I have added following mapped interceptor. In this way it will be called for all requests coming to any controller.

```
@Bean
    public MappedInterceptor myMappedInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/**"}, getSecurityInterceptor());
    }
```

Reference 
[How to add Custom Interceptor in Spring data rest (spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916260/how-to-add-custom-interceptor-in-spring-data-rest-spring-data-rest-webmvc-2-3-0/32952220?noredirect=1#comment53868161_32952220)