# Spring Interceptor is not compatible with @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-rest

```
@Component
    public class TestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("afterCompletion");
        }
        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("postHandle");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("preHandle");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class AnnotationSecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
    }
}
```

finally the entity is presented as REST using a @RepositoryRestController as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = UserSummaryProjection.class)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

Then calling

```
curl -X GET https://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
```

but the interceptor is not called.

Because the REST resource is managed Spring Data Rest with **@RepositoryRestController the interceptor is not called**. But if I write the REST resource with **@RestController it will work**.

How can I make interceptors work with **@RepositoryRestController**?

Comment: have you tried to annotate `TestInterceptor` with `@Component` annotation?

Comment: Just tried, same thing

Comment: If `TestInterceptor` is scanned and managed by the container then you should inject it instead of doing `new TestInterceptor()`. Does it work this way? `@Autowired TestInterceptor testInterceptor;` And `registry.addInterceptor(testInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/**");`

Comment: Just tried autowire, same thing

Comment: make sure testinterceptor bean is being created and injected into the configuration bean? Before line `registry.addInterceptor...`,  `assert testInterceptor != null;` ?

Comment: @erotsppa I have tested it and everything is okay, just do the changes as per the answer and to make sure just try to test it as `"/**"` instead of `"/api/**"`

Comment: Can I see your sample project? I used your code and it did not call

Comment: Did you try also to manually create it? in the configuration class create the object in a method annotated with `@Bean`?

Comment: @lainatnavi Yep same thing

Comment: I discovered that It seems to work for custom controllers but not for @RepositoryRestResource

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh I just edited it thanks. It does not work.

Comment: @erotsppa when there are major changes you have to ask a new question instead of keep changing the question, people spend their time and efforts to help you to understand some points or to replay to your question, therefore you have to be faithful for their effort.

Comment: Have u tried creating a MappedInterceptor Bean as stated e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55801861/11133168 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952220/11133168 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working (on `/` context path, and a simple `User` class, spring-boot v2.4.2) with the following config/spring-boot app:

```
...
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor
...    

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
       
    @Bean
    public org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(
                new String[]{"/users/**"},  // null => maps to any repository/path
                new MyInterceptorImpl()
        );
    }

    private class MyInterceptorImpl implements HandlerInterceptor  {
         @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("preHandle");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("postHandle");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("afterCompletion");
        }
    }
}
```

I used a simplified:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> { }
```

Comment: I don't want to seem rude but you should at least acknowledge the original author(s) of this solution by referencing it...you even have a wrong comment in your code from mixing up the two answers I linked in my comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176504/spring-interceptor-is-not-compatible-with-repositoryrestresource#comment117064097_66176504

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `TestInterceptor` as a bean and anotate it with `@Autowired` just add these changes to register the Interceptor into Interceptor Registry :

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TestInterceptor testInterceptor;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(testInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
    }
```

HandlerInterceptor :

```
@Component
public class TestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestInterceptor.class);
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("afterCompletion");
            long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
            logger.info("Request URL::" + arg0.getRequestURL().toString() +
                    ":: Start Time=" + Instant.now());
            arg0.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
        }
        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("postHandle");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("preHandle");
            return true;
        }
}
```

as a sample i have changed the '/api/**' to '/**' and here a log sample as the below :

```
2021-02-13 00:36:31.075  INFO 14340 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 22 ms
preHandle
postHandle
afterCompletion
2021-02-13 00:36:35.300  INFO 14340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.TestInterceptor         : Request URL::http://localhost:8080/time:: Start Time=2021-02-12T22:36:35.289832Z
```

Answer (score 0):

It only worked for me, using Spring Boot 2.6.7, by adding a MappedInterceptor.

```
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor loggingMappedInterceptor(TestInterceptor testInterceptor) {
    return new MappedInterceptor(
            null,  // => maps to any repository
            testInterceptor);
}
```