# Setup X-Total-Count with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm testing Spring Data REST.
I was following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) to understand how it works.

The code so far is simple as:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq", sequenceName="user_id_seq")
@Table(name = "employees")
data class Employee (@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq") val id: Long? = null,
                     val name: String = "defConstructorHell")
```

and when I ask with `GET` I obtain the following json:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "employees" : [ {
      "name" : "ciao",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:5000/api/employees/1"
        },
        "employee" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:5000/api/employees/1"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:5000/api/employees{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:5000/api/profile/employees"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Which is totally fine but I'm using a js framework that requires the header X-Total-Count.

Do you know if there is a way of doing it wi Spring Data REST?

Comment: Did you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/19251846/5380322 ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I added a controller that add the requested header:

```
@RepositoryRestController
class EmployeeController @Autowired constructor(val repo: EmployeeRepository) {

    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(GET),
            path = arrayOf("employees"))
    @ResponseBody
    fun getEmployees(@RequestParam("_sort", required = false, defaultValue = "id") _sort: String,
                     @RequestParam("_order", required = false, defaultValue = "DESC") _order: String,
                     @RequestParam("_start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") _start: Int,
                     @RequestParam("_end", required = false, defaultValue = "20") _end: Int): ResponseEntity<MutableIterable<Employee>> {
        val pr = PageRequest(_start, 20, Sort.Direction.valueOf(_order), _sort)
        val result = repo.findAll(pr)
        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers.add("X-Total-Count", result.count().toString())
        return ResponseEntity(result.content, headers, OK)
    }
}
```