# How to add custom headers to a specific resource in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-mvc, header, spring-data-rest

One of my entities in Spring Data Rest has an attribute value that should be added to the response's headers. How to do this?

I already found ways to change *default* headers (for all responses) with handler interceptors. And I also found stuff about version, etag and modified.. 
These are not the things what I want.

The header must be set on 1 of REST resources and the value is instance/record dependent.

As an illustration: `Person` has the attribute `age`. Every request to the Person REST resource (GET `/person/{id}` for example) must return the value of `age` as a http header (eg: `age:32`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19265876/5380322

Comment: An interceptor can be mapped to specific paths. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/MappedInterceptor.html#getPathPatterns-- You'd still need to get a reference to the person to get the age however

Comment: I mentioned that i need record specific headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my previous answer I can see that the most recent versions of the SDR API have a method `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration#httpHeadersPreparer()`.

I can see this method is available in 2.6.8 but was not in the version I am currently using 2.5.10.

So it looks like you could do something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
{
  @Override
  public HttpHeadersPreparer httpHeadersPreparer()
  {
    HttpHeadersPreparer preparer = new HttpHeadersPreparer(){
      @Override
      public HttpHeaders prepareHeaders(PersistentEntityResource resource, Object value)
      {
        org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = super.prepareHeaders(resource);

        if(value instanceof Person){
          headers.add("age", ((Person)value).getAge());
        }
      }

    };

    return preparer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Alan, thanks so much. This looks like a good solution. However, by extending RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration other configurations seem to dissappear.

Comment: Well that depends on your existing config. You need to update that inline with the solution.

Comment: Seems to be an old issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392

Comment: Thanks Alan, it works now. Any idea how to implement this for a collection of resources? (the list of persons `/person`)

Comment: I am guessing in that in that case the value parameter will be a `Collection<Person>` so do whatever you need to with that.

Comment: Well, the request doesn't visit the override at all.`HttpHeaders prepareHeaders(PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity, Object value)` is what I have.

Comment: I don't know. You should accept this answer and open another question.

Comment: The fact it is not called makes sense if you consider its purpose which is to set Etag and last-modified headers for an Entity. Neither of these things are relevant on a collection resource. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/HttpHeadersPreparer.html#HttpHeadersPreparer-- If think if you need all this you can go with my previous answer and store a List<Person> in the the TheadLocal contex and the  entity listener adds a Person on each load.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can bind an interceptor to specific paths so that is half the problem solved.

The second issue is getting a reference to the Person resource that has been requested. You could look at using a ThreadLocal here:

```
public class PersonContext{
    private static ThreadLocal<Person> context  = new ThreadLocal<Person>();

    public static Person getPerson(Person person){
        return context.get();
    }

    public static void setPerson(Person person){
        context.set(person);
    }

    public static void cleanUp(){
        context.remove();
    }
}
```

A standard JPA Entity Listener can be used to bind a reference to the loaded Person:

```
public class PersonListener{

    @PostLoad
    public void setContext(Person person){
        PersonContext.set(person);
    }
}
```

The Entity listener can be registered on the Entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(PersonListener.class)
public class Person(){

}
```

In the interceptor you can obtain a reference to the Person bound to the context in the current thread and set the header accordingly:

```
public class PersonInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){
            Person person = PersonContext.getPerson();
            response.addHeader("age",  person.getAge());
        }

        PersonContext.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Finally register your interceptor with Spring Data Rest:

```
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor myMappedInterceptor() {
    return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"person/**"}, new PersonInterceptor());
}
```

Issues:

- the post load listener will execute on every load of a Person even on other paths and so clean-up needs to be better. Register a 2nd interceptor on all paths to handle clean-up??

An alternative apporach the could be to requery the database in your interceptor. So the above could be replaced with an interceptor something like:

```
public class PersonInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);

        if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){
           Long personID = // Extract id by examining request.getServletPath();
           Person person = repository.findOne(personID);
           response.addHeader("age",  person.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

This would have the overhead of an additional query but this could probably be avoided by configuring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter which should mean it is fetched from the 1st level cache.