# How I can access to headers value using Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I have a rest web service based on Spring data rest to generate the API

this my api :

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "cardInfos", collectionResourceRel = "cardInfos", excerptProjection = CardInfoDetailView.class)
public interface CardInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Card> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Card c")
    Page<Card> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I can get object from my service using this url using an http GET method :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8089/test-app/v1/cardInfos?cardNumber=1234
or : 
http://127.0.0.1:8089/test-app/v1/cardInfos?page=0&size=5
```

I want to set some values on the http header during the GET call and retrive those values somewhere in my service I used to use  `@RequestHeader HttpHeaders` headers is this possible using Spring Rest Data ?

Comment: You can achieve the header value(s) in controller mappings (methods). Could you post your controller class where your rest mappings are defined?

Comment: There is no controller the service is exposed using @RepositoryRestResource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom default headers for REST API only using Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251846/custom-default-headers-for-rest-api-only-using-spring-data-rest)

Comment: You can have Spring wire the `HttpServletRequest` into your service and access headers via that. Otherwise, have a `ServletFilter` or Spring Interceptor intercept the request. Form here you can put the value in a `ThreadLocal` and access where required. 
 [1] https://stackoverflow.com/q/3320674/1356423, [2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/53100895/1356423