# How to get user info directly at JPA level in rest api

Tags: rest, jpa, stateless, audit-trail

I am using REST api with JPA, and getting the user information in the header section .
For audit purpose need to save the user detail with each request.
How to directly get the user info at JPA level (@Prepersist and @PreUpdate hooks) from rest header.

I don't want to pass the details though service layer
Is there any generic way to do it ?

Note-I am not using spring.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem with spring framework. Following idea may help you.

1. Create AppContext using ThreadLocal

   ```
   public class AppContext {

   private static final ThreadLocal<User> currentUser = new ThreadLocal<>();

   public static void setCurrentUser(String tenant) {
       currentUser.set(tenant);
   }

   public static String getCurrentUser() {
       return currentUser.get();
   }

   public static void clear() {
       currentUser.remove();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Use filter or similar  to get user from http header and set to the AppContext

   ```
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        // Your code to extract user info from header
        // Build user object and set to the AppContext
        AppContext.setCurrentUser(user);

       //doFilter
       chain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
   }
   ```
3. Use AppContext on the repository. It should available on request scope.

   ```
     @PrePersist
     public void onPrePersist() {
       if(AppContext.getCurrentUser() != null){
           this.user = AppContext.getCurrentUser();
        }
   }
   ```

   }